# What is wrong specifically with my code?

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# (I started in January) and I need help with my code that I'm writing. On all the lines that come up with an error, it says

> expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Here's my code:

```
using System;

namespace pawlowski_Catherine_Lab3

{
    public class Course
    {
        protected string description;
        protected string prefix;
        protected double number;
        protected double hours;

    }
    public Course ()
    {
        this.hours="3.00";
    }
    public Course(string description, string prefix, double number, double hours)
    {
        this.description=description;
        this.prefix=prefix;
        this.number=number;
        this.hours=hours;
    }
    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return string.Format ("Course: "+prefix+"\nCourse Number: "+number+"\nDescription: "+description+"\nCredit hours: "+hours);
    }
}
```

Pretty much, where the errors are, are on anything saying public at the beginning except the first one. Please help me figure out what specifically I'm doing wrong so I can fix it myself in the future.

Comment: You have an extra `}` before your first constructor (`public Course ()`)

Comment: Hi and welcome from a fellow (past) resident of Kennesaw :), please consider being more specific about the errors. Give the actual error log output.

Comment: If you indent your code, it should be pretty easy to spot the error. In Visual Studio: Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document.

Comment: @Steve, I'm failing to see the `}` you speak of...

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils after the property declarations, all of the constructors should be within the class declaration.

Comment: @Steve, I'm apparently blind, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will likely get closed, so:

Here's what you have (formatted):

```
using System;

namespace pawlowski_Catherine_Lab3 {
    public class Course {
        protected string description;
        protected string prefix;
        protected double number;
        protected double hours;

    }
    public Course() {
        this.hours = "3.00";
    }
    public Course(string description, string prefix, double number, double hours) {
        this.description = description;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.number = number;
        this.hours = hours;
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("Course: " + prefix + "\nCourse Number: " + number + "\nDescription: " + description + "\nCredit hours: " + hours);
    }
}
```

Here's what you should have (the constructor and methods are part of the class):

```
using System;

namespace pawlowski_Catherine_Lab3 {
    public class Course {
        protected string description;
        protected string prefix;
        protected double number;
        protected double hours;

        public Course() {
            this.hours = "3.00";
        }
        public Course(string description, string prefix, double number, double hours) {
            this.description = description;
            this.prefix = prefix;
            this.number = number;
            this.hours = hours;
        }
        public override string ToString() {
            return string.Format("Course: " + prefix + "\nCourse Number: " + number + "\nDescription: " + description + "\nCredit hours: " + hours);
        }
    }
}
```

Correct indenting is your friend here.

Comment: Yes, I think I get it now! Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

> You should place all method and properties inside of the class
>   declaration.

Something like :

```
using System;
namespace pawlowski_Catherine_Lab3
{
    public class Course
    {
        protected string description;
        protected string prefix;
        protected double number;
        protected double hours;

        public Course ()
        {
            this.hours="3.00";
        }
        public Course(string description, string prefix, double number, double hours)
        {
            this.description=description;
            this.prefix=prefix;
            this.number=number;
            this.hours=hours;
        }
        public override string ToString ()
        {
            return string.Format ("Course: "+prefix+"\nCourse Number: "+number+"\nDescription: "+description+"\nCredit hours: "+hours);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer

Comment: Ok. That's more like an answer now (*by adding some codes to your post*)

Comment: Yes, I think i get it now! So, it's mainly that I need everything within the curly brackets after the public class course part? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In the lines here:

```
public class Course
{
    protected string description;
    protected string prefix;
    protected double number;
    protected double hours;
} // Get rid of this line here
public Course ()
{
    ...
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I think I see why this isn't useful. It's because there isn't a line converting it to where the computer can read it, right? Thank you so much for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Declare your contractor and method inside the class scope.

Replace your code
with this

```
using System;

namespace pawlowski_Catherine_Lab3
{
    public class Course
    {
        protected string description;
        protected string prefix;
        protected double number;
        protected double hours;

        public Course ()
        {
            this.hours="3.00";
        }
        public Course(string description, string prefix, double number, double hours)
        {
            this.description=description;
            this.prefix=prefix;
            this.number=number;
            this.hours=hours;
        }
        public override string ToString ()
        {
            return string.Format ("Course: "+prefix+"\nCourse Number:     "+number+"\nDescription: "+description+"\nCredit hours: "+hours);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, I think I get it now! Thank you so much for your response!